# If $\int_A f d\nu = \int_A f d\nu'$ for some $f>0$ and all measurable $A$, does $\nu$ equal $\nu'$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu,\nu'$ be finite measures (same total mass) on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with Borel sigma-algebra), and $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow (0,1)$ be a  measurable function.

Note: $f$ is fixed (this the the point of difference to similar questions that have been asked).

Suppose that for all Borel sets $A$

$$\int_A f d\nu = \int_A f d\nu'.$$

Is it then true that $\nu=\nu'$? Is this a simple consequence of a particular well known theorem?

A reference would be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: The hypothesis is that $\mu=\mu'$ where the measures $\mu$ and $\mu'$ are uniquely defined by the conditions that $d\mu/d\nu=f=d\mu'/d\nu'$. Now consider $g=1/f$, hence $g>0$ everywhere, and compute $\int_Agd\mu=\int_Agd\mu'$. Ergo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true.
Use a monotone class method to prove that for every positive Borel function $g$, we have 
$$\int fg d\nu = \int fg d\nu'$$

Take any Borel set $A$ and define $g = \frac{1}{f}\mathbf{1}_A$. This yelds $\int \mathbf{1}_A d\nu = \int \mathbf{1}_A d\nu'$, that is $\nu(A) = \nu'(A)$.

Comment: What is the uniform measure?

Comment: $f$ must not be zero!

Comment: Damned, $f$ cannot be null ! I'll correct my answer.

Comment: f is positive in my question

Comment: Yes, the answer have been updated and nows seems to be correct.